# ignore specific directories in htaccess using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following code in my .htaccess to strip out index.php from the urls in my CMS-based site.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This code works great and it routes requests exactly how I want.  For example, with URL: `http://example.com/contact/` the directory `contact` doesn't actually exist if you look in the FTP; instead `index.php` handles the request and shows my contact info.  Perfect.  Well, almost perfect.

I want to modify this code to specify a couple directories in FTP that should be ignored.  For example, if I've got a folder called `assets`, when I go to `http://example.com/assets/` the default DirectoryIndex page is displayed.  Instead, I want this directory to be ignored -- I want index.php to handle /assets/.

TL;DR: How can I modify the above code to explicitly ignore certain existing directories (so that index.php handles them instead of the DirectoryIndex)?

Comment: This is similar to a few other questions I saw, but I didn't see any that matched my specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not adding this below or before your code?

```
RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```